# how to using the word "mystery"

Tags: vocabulary

Semantics can help to solve the **"mystery in  the concept of the sentences"**

Would you help me correct the bold part, as I know it is poor English.

Thanks

Comment: Not necessarily. But without CONTEXT (ring a bell?) we can't give you a good answer.

Comment: "the mystery in/of the concept of the sentences" sounds a bit awkward to me. I think you mean either *Semantics can help solve the ambiguities in sentences* or *Semantics can help us solve the mystery of the concept of sentence structure*.

Comment: Semantics can help solve the sentence concept mystery.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Semantics can help to solve the mystery of the concept of sentences

Comment: Two Downvotes? Why? What's wrong?

Comment: I can guess at why you may have been downvoted.  The bold part of the original question isn't necessarily wrong.  Your suggestion may be an improvement, it may not be.  It may be that neither the original sentence nor yours is actually expressing what the OP means to express.  There is no way of knowing, because he didn't give any context.  In your answer you just suggest a wording, but don't explain precisely which possible meaning it conveys.